# How to insert multiple rows into MySQL with different userids in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, servlets, arraylist

I have been trying to implement a code that would retrieve an arraylist of userids from a one table in MySQL and then using the retrieved values to make a bulk/batch insert into another table from the same MySQL database. The size or length of the batch insert must be same as the arraylist of userids that was retrieved.

I have tried to retrieve userids using a model class and then using a for loop to insert other data including the various userids into the database.

SubscribersServlet.java

```
 public static void bulkNotify(List<Notify> notifyList) {

    String sql = "insert into attnotif (attndid,sender,title,message,urgency,artistid) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try (Connection connection = DBConnect.getConnection()) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                for (Notify notify : notifyList) {

                    ps.setInt(1, notify.getuserid());
                    ps.setString(2, notify.getSender());
                    ps.setString(3, notify.getNotifytitle());
                    ps.setString(4, notify.getNotifymessage());
                    ps.setString(5, notify.getNotifyurgency());
                    ps.setInt(6, notify.getArtistid());

                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to insert title, message, urgency, artistid (all with same value) and userid (different values) into multiple rows in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a counter in your for loop, and after that counter hits a limit, you should call executeBatch() method.

```
    for (Notify notify : notifyList) {

        /**
         * do sth
         * */

        i++;

        if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == notifyList.size()) {
            ps.executeBatch(); // pile up 1000 items then load
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the size of the notifyList is 1002?

Comment: Good point. Getting the list's size, assigning the limit so that it would be a no remainder divider to that size and assigning it before the for loop will do the trick I guess.

Comment: How do i get the userid array to know the size of the batch update? The size of the batch is dependent on the userids that must be retrieved using select before the insert method. If am getting the whole process wrong, i would appreciate clarification.

Comment: @Sedrick that is what the `i == entities.size()` is for I am guessing, but it should be `i == notifyList.count()` I think.

Comment: After taking a second look, it does make sense. Sorry.